# Why does STL map core dump on find?

Tags: c++, gcc, dictionary

So, I have this situation where I need to see if an object is in my stl map.  If it isn't, I am going to add it.

```
char symbolName[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
map<string,TheObject> theMap;
if (theMap.find(symbolName)==theMap.end()) {
            TheObject theObject(symbolName);
            theMap.insert(pair<string, TheObject>(symbolName,
                    theObject));
}
```

I am getting a core dump on the: theMap.find when the object is not already in the map.
Supposedly, if the item is not in the map, it is supposed to return an iterator equivelent to map::end

What is going on here?

GCC: 3.4.6

Comment: Well... it would help to know what `TheObject::TheObject(???)` is.

Comment: As a side note, you can just do char symbolName[] = "Hello";

Comment: it doesn't matter what it is?  It is just an object being "hashed."

Comment: map could be implemented as binary tree

Comment: It almost certainly is implemented as a binary tree.

Comment: Does it being implemented as a binary tree matter?

Comment: Never mind, I see that the key is string, not TheObject. What is the callstack at the crash? Just saying it crashes in map.find isn't that helpful.

Comment: Not in most cases, but if you've overloaded your operator<, a binary tree will use that in searching, where a hash_map wouldn't have to.

Comment: What is the actual declaration of theMap? Include the entire type definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can crash because of many reasons. Without knowing the definition of at least `TheObject`'s constructors, i think we are largely left to guess at the problem. So far, your code looks fine, but it can be simplified:

```
char symbolName[] = "Hello";
map<string,TheObject> theMap;
theMap.insert(make_pair(symbolName, TheObject(symbolName)));
```

It won't do anything if the symbol is already mapped, discarding the new TheObject object.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do it this way?

```
char symbolName[] = "hello";
theMap.insert(pair<string, TheObject>(symbolName, TheObject(symbolName)));
```

If your map is a `map<string, TheObject>` then you WILL get a core dump if you try to search for NULL:

```
// This will core dump:
char *symbolName = NULL; // Oops!
theMap.find(symbolName); // Kabang!
```

Comment: if just insert TheObject(symbolName) and there is already an instance of TheObject for that symbolName, then it will overwrite it.

Comment: No, if the key is already there, insert won't do anything (indicated by false in the second value in the returned pair.)

Comment: +1 Nice one Josh - why write all the extra code when STL will do the check for you

Answer (score 3):

Check whether your STL map is empty() before doing a find(). Some STL implementations are buggy when executing a find() on an empty STL map.

Comment: It is almost certainly empty.  Is this a problem?  Why?

Comment: I have my doubts as to how often this shows up, but this thread talks about something like this: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t278300-stdmapfind-throws-exception-when-map-is-empty.html

Answer (score 2):

By the way, there are two possible simplifications.

First, use `make_pair` instead of using the `pair` constructor. This means you don't have to specify the type arguments explicitly:

```
theMap.insert(make_pair(symbolName, theObject));
```

Second, instead of your code you can simply write:

```
theMap[symbolName] = theObject;
```

Comment: IIRC, accessing an STL map using the bracket operator if the key doesn't exist in the map returns NULL or throws an exception -- either way, the end result of the assignment is you get an exception.

Comment: No - it will create the entry if needed using the values default constructor.

Comment: @rmeador: no. The bracket operator has this very important and widely ignored side-effect. It's the reason why there's no `const` version of this operator, a fact that irritates people to no ends.

Comment: it will, however, overwrite any previously stored TheObject object. if it has mutable state, it may change matters.

Comment: I stand corrected, having just read the docs... I also know that I ran into the situation I described in my first comment.  The only explanation I can think of is that the type I had in my map didn't have a default constructor, but I question whether that would compile at all...

Answer (score 2):

Post your real code, or at least a complete example that exhibits the behavior you're describing.  Sometimes the problem is a subtlety lost in the translation when you try to debug make-believe code written just to post in forums like this.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work fine.

The only possible problem is inside TheObject implementation, but it shouldn't affect the find call.

Also, can be some unrelated issue, like [Buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) due to some code executed before it.

Comment: It doesn't work though.  Codelogic mentioned that there might be a problem if the tree is empty to start, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Can you add the definition of TheObject class? And what compiler are you using?

Comment: I cannot add a definition of the class.  Version of the compiler is gcc 3.4.6

Answer (score 1):

As addition to the code simplifications:

Use std::string instead of char[] and use it inside of your class definition for TheObject too.

Not sure what your TheObject class is doing w/ the char array, but if you use the map outside of the scope of this function, eg. by using it as return value, i bet there is somewhere an object pointing to the adress of symbolName, which is not defined anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get a core dump; the code works for me.

There are opportunities to make your code simpler and more readable:

- As someone else noted, you can simplify the insertion to `theMap[symbolName] = TheObject(symbolName)`
- I might be wrong, but as far as I know { 'a', 'b', '\0' } is the same as "abc", so you could simplify to `char symbolName[] = "Hello";` I have the impression that the non-idiomatic definition is confusing some people here.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using it in a constructor.  I had a similar problem when using map inside constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem like this by using pointers to my map objects.  Since used in constructor, they needed to be pointers and then inside constructor I new'ed them .